# Eigenvalue decomposition fails with armadillo eigs_sym() for too large matrices

Tags: c++, armadillo

I have recently installed armadillo and tried eigenvalue problem for sparse matrices. Unfortunately, decomposition fails is the parameter 'N' (code below) is too large e.q. 1000. I wonder what is going on here. Matrix is not very complicated - it has diagonal structure.

**UPDATE**

Mathematica also have problems with this matrix. It tells me that Arnoldi algorithm does not converge. Maybe I need to manually specify some parameters in arnoldi arpack routines to ensure convergence?

Here is my code:

```
#include <armadillo>

int main ()
{
    double N = 1000.0;

    // create matrix
    int kmin = 0;
    int kmax = static_cast<int>( std::floor( N/2.0 ) );
    int dim = (kmax - kmin) + 1;

    // locations and values in sparse matrices
    arma::umat hc_locations (2, 3*dim-2);
    arma::vec hc_values (3*dim-2);

    // diagonal part
    for (int k=0; k<dim; k++)
    {
        hc_locations (0,k) = k;
        hc_locations (1,k) = k;
        hc_values (k) = 2.0/N*static_cast<double>(kmin + k)*( 2.0*( N-2.0*static_cast<double>(k + kmin) ) - 1.0 );

    }
    // upper and lower diagonal
    for (int k=0; k<dim-1; k++)
    {
        hc_locations (0,k+dim) = k;
        hc_locations (1,k+dim) = k+1;
        hc_values (k+dim) = 2.0/N*std::sqrt( ( static_cast<double>(k+1+kmin) ) *
                                             ( static_cast<double>(k+1+kmin) ) *
                                             ( N - static_cast<double>(2*(k+1+kmin)) + 1.0 ) * 
                                             ( N - static_cast<double>(2*(k+1+kmin)) + 2.0 ) );

        hc_locations (0, k+2*dim-1) = k+1;
        hc_locations (1, k+2*dim-1) = k;
        hc_values (k+2*dim-1) = 2.0/N*std::sqrt ( ( static_cast<double>(k+1+kmin) ) * 
                                                   ( static_cast<double>(k+1+kmin) ) *
                                                   ( N - static_cast<double>(2*(k+kmin)) ) *
                                                   ( N - static_cast<double>(2*(k+kmin)) - 1.0 ) );
    }

    arma::sp_mat Ham(hc_locations, hc_values);

    // eigenvalue problem
    arma::vec eigval;
    arma::mat eigvec;

    arma::eigs_sym( eigval, eigvec, Ham, 3, "sa");
```

}

Answer (score 1):

For small matrices of size 2000 or so, it is often time easier to find all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, as those methods are less susceptible to near singular matrices.

I replaced your code

```
arma::eigs_sym( eigval, eigvec, Ham, 3, "sa");
```

with

```
arma::mat fullMat = arma::mat(Ham);
arma::eig_sym( eigval, eigvec, fullMat);
```

and the compiled program takes less than a second to solve on my late 2015 Macbook Pro.

Comment: I have solved the issue a while ago. The problem lies in ARPACK library, More specifically, Armadillo library does not allow you to specify size of the Krylov basis and max number of iterations as the original ARPACK library does. Distance between smallest eigenvalues of this matrix is too small for basis of order 5 (default Armadillo 2*nev+1). I wrote similar program in fortran and for matrix size N=10000 I needed basis size of order 90 in order to converge using Arnoldi iteration. Also Mathematica 10.0 let you specify number of basis vectors and max iterations. It works.